# A probability inequality

Tags: probability, inequality

Let $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},P)$ be a probability space. Assume $X_1,X_2,Y_1,Y_2$ are four random variables. Assume $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent. Is it necessarily true that $$E\big|E(X_1|Y_1)-E(X_2|Y_2)\big|\leq E|X_1-X_2|?$$ If $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ generate the same $\sigma$-algebra, then this is simply Jensen's inequality. How about for arbitrary $Y_1$ and $Y_2$?

Thanks!